# Использование condition_variable в с++11 и с++17. Не одинаковый ход выполнения программы

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, c++17, condition-variable

Запускаю тот же код в разных IDE и получаю разные результаты.

В VS2013(с++11) выполняется как и ожидаю: число заносится в массив в одном потоке, второй поток просыпается и читает число. Через секунду все повторяется.
В VS2017(с++17) выполняется по-другому: Второй поток просыпается только в конце, когда завершается первый поток, убивая свой mutex и выводит сразу все 10 чисел через 10 секунд.
Почему такое различие?
[Пример](https://ideone.com/WVqGIg)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include<future>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

template<int max_number>
void data_preparation_tread(shared_ptr<mutex>& mut, shared_ptr<vector<int>>& data_queue, shared_ptr<condition_variable>& data_cond)
{
    while (true)
    {
        static int x = 0;
        x++;
        lock_guard<mutex> ld(*mut);
        data_queue->push_back(x);
        data_cond->notify_one();
        chrono::milliseconds ms(1000);
        this_thread::sleep_for(ms);
        if (x == max_number)
            break;
    }
}

template<int max_number>
void data_processing_thread(shared_ptr<mutex>& mut, shared_ptr<vector<int>>& data_queue, shared_ptr<condition_variable>& data_cond)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<mutex> lk(*mut);
        data_cond->wait(lk, [=]{
            if (data_queue->empty())
            {
                cout << endl << "Fault wake up" << endl;
            }
            return !data_queue->empty();
        });
        int number{};
        while (data_queue->size() > 0)
        {
            number = data_queue->back();
            data_queue->pop_back();
            cout << "Number:" << number << "   " << "Buffer length:" << data_queue->size() << endl;
        }
        lk.unlock();
        if (number == max_number)
            break;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    shared_ptr<mutex> mut = make_shared<mutex>();
    shared_ptr<vector<int>> data_queue = make_shared<vector<int>>();
    shared_ptr<condition_variable> data_cond = make_shared<condition_variable>();
    void(*pdata_procc)(std::shared_ptr<std::mutex>& mut, shared_ptr<vector<int>>& data_queue, shared_ptr<condition_variable>& data_cond) = data_processing_thread<10>;
    void(*pdata_prepar)(std::shared_ptr<std::mutex>& mut, shared_ptr<vector<int>>& data_queue, shared_ptr<condition_variable>& data_cond) = data_preparation_tread<10>;

    std::thread processing = thread(pdata_procc, ref(mut), ref(data_queue), ref(data_cond));
    std::thread preparation = thread(pdata_prepar, ref(mut), ref(data_queue), ref(data_cond));
    processing.join();
    preparation.join();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите на функцию data_preparation_tread - мютекс блокирует почти все тело. Только инкремент `x++`. Поэтому, шансов, что кто то пролезет через эту блокировку - очень мало. Самый простой способ исправить - это добавить пару скобок

```
static int x = 0;
x++;
{
    lock_guard<mutex> ld(*mut);
    data_queue->push_back(x);
    data_cond->notify_one();
}
chrono::milliseconds ms(1000);
this_thread::sleep_for(ms);
if (x == max_number)
    break;
```

Почему оно работало раньше? ну видимо везло, менеджер потоков по другому разбрасывал.

BTW - код написан очень странно (вот это `template<typename int max_number>`, например) - не компилируется ни gcc, ни clang, пришлось порезать шаблоны.

Comment: В книге С++ Concurrency in action без скобок. Со скобками: тогда во втором потоке постоянно будет срабатывать "Fault wake up". И в 2013 студии это работает идеально

Comment: да, срабатывает. Но там в книге другой код.

Comment: принцип тот-же. только через глобальные переменные а не через shared_ptr.

Comment: @YuryMelnikov не верю...

Comment: @PavelMayorov зуб даю